# using a fork and pipe to mimic linux pipe command

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, exec

My goal is to mimic the linux pipe command for example ls | sort. instead of simply sort. but instead of typing | the user types : for example `"./program ls : sort" == "ls | sort"` I need to complete this task using a fork() and a pipe(). i have a MRE setup that only allows me to run one command at a time but i have no idea as to how to make it to where the stdout is the stdin for the second command. whenever i attempt to `dup() close() and exec()` in the parent something seems to be going wrong? I have a setup where parse the input given by the user and i acquire argA for argument A which contains the command like ls or sort, and ArgAP for argument A parameter in case the user wants to specify -lh or -r etc. same thing for argB.

I have this program currently setup to be hardcoded to execute the bc command but that can be easily fixed by assigning some parameters around. please help me as i am firmly stuck on this!

```
 //################  #-for include
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <dirent.h>
 //################

int main(int b, char ** locations) {

    int ok = 0;
    int dots = 0;
    char argA[1000];
    char argB[1000];
    char argAP[1000];
    char argBP[1000];
    while (locations[ok] != NULL) {
        //printf("%s \n", locations[ok]);
        if (strcmp(locations[ok], ":") == 0) {
            dots = 1;
        }
        ok++;
    } //printf("%s %d \n", locations[2], b);

    strcpy(argA, "");
    strcpy(argB, "");
    strcpy(argAP, "");
    strcpy(argBP, "");

    if (dots == 0) {
        int x = 1;
        strcat(argA, locations[x]);
        strcat(argA, " ");
        x++;
        while (locations[x] != NULL) {
            strcat(argAP, locations[x]);
            strcat(argAP, " ");
            x++;
        }
        printf("%s%s \n", argA, argAP);
    }

    if (dots == 1) {
        int x = 1;
        int compare = strcmp(locations[x], ":");

        if (strcmp(locations[1], ":") == 0) {
            printf("one arg\n");
            strcat(argA, locations[x]);
            strcat(argA, " ");
            x++;
            while (locations[x] != NULL) {
                strcat(argAP, locations[x]);
                strcat(argAP, " ");
                x++;
            }
            printf("%s%s \n", argA, argAP);

        } else {
            printf("two args\n");
            strcat(argA, locations[x]);
            strcat(argA, " ");
            compare = strcmp(locations[x], ":");
            x++;
            compare = strcmp(locations[x], ":");
            while (compare != 0) {
                printf("%d \n", x);
                strcat(argAP, locations[x]);
                strcat(argAP, " ");
                compare = strcmp(locations[x], ":");
                x++;
            }
            printf("argA: %s%s \n", argA, argAP);
            x++;
            strcat(argB, locations[x]);
            strcat(argB, " ");
            x++;
            while (locations[x] != NULL) {
                strcat(argBP, locations[x]);
                strcat(argBP, " ");
                x++;
            }
            printf("argB: %s%s \n", argB, argBP);
        }

    }

    // fork/piping

    int i, n;
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    int rd = fd[0]; // rd points to 0 (read) in pipe
    int wt = fd[1]; // wt points to 1 (write) in pipe

    if (fork()) {

        close(rd);
        write(wt, "2*1*9*1", strlen("2*1*9*1"));

        write(wt, "\n", 1);
        close(wt);
        exit(0);

    } else {

        close(wt);
        close(0); // close zero
        dup(rd); // dup rd into lowest possible orbit
        close(rd);
        execlp("bc", "bc", 0, NULL); // reading from zero means reading from rd!

        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have commented off the section where i need the help. how do i feed the results through the fork using the pipe of one command into the second? I deem this as nearly impossible as through my attempts i have only been able to get only one command working through this setup that i have written here.

Comment: That is a large function, this `main()` of yours. Maybe split it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ORIGINAL

Once you want to replace the `stdin` of the child process, you need to use `dup2()` function.

Here is the manual section that explains why the `dup()` function will never work for your purposes:

> The  dup() system call creates a copy of the file descriptor oldfd,
> using the lowest-numbered unused file descriptor for the new
> descriptor.

Here is the manual section that explains why the `dup2()` function can solve your problem:

> The dup2() system call performs the same task as dup(), but instead
> of using the lowest-numbered unused file descriptor, it uses the file
> descriptor number specified in newfd.

To solve your problem, replace the `dup(rd)` call for `dup2(rd, STDIN_FILENO)`. You may also remove the `close(0)` call, once the `dup2()` function closes the `newfd` if it is already in use.

> If the file descriptor newfd was previously open, it is silently
> closed before being reused.

### EDIT #1

What I previously wrote does not fix the problem, once `close(0); dup(rd);` will have the same effect as `dup2(rd, 0)`, as [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600898/user4815162342) mentioned below. So, I compiled your code as it is and, after running, I
had this result:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -o program program.c
$ ./program ls : sort
two args
argA: ls  
argB: sort  
18
$
```

As you can see, the last line shows `18`, the result of `2*1*9*1`.
Now, notice that the parent process exits right after it writes to the file described as `wt` - the new `stdin` of `bc` command being executed in the child process. This means that the parent process may exit before the child process is done. I highly recommend you to test your code using a `wait()` or `waitpid()` call right before the parent process exits. For example:

```
// (...)

if (fork()) {
    close(rd);
    write(wt, "2*1*9*1", strlen("2*1*9*1"));
    write(wt, "\n", 1);
    close(wt);
    wait(NULL);
    exit(0);
} else {
    close(wt);
    close(0); // close zero
    dup(rd); // dup rd into lowest possible orbit
    close(rd);
    execlp("bc", "bc", NULL);
    exit(1);
}
```

I also replaced the line `execlp("bc", "bc", 0, NULL);` with the line `execlp("bc", "bc", NULL);`. The zero I removed is equivalent to `NULL` and means the end of the argument list for the command being executed with `execlp()`.

### EDIT #2 (IMPLEMENTATION)

Reading the entire code, we can divide your implementation in **two parts**:

1. Parsing the program's arguments to fit the syntax of the `execlp()` function;
2. Forking the process to execute the second command with the result of the first command as input.

If you read the man pages of the `exec()` function family, you will notice that the function `execvp()` is way more useful in this program, since the second argument of the `execvp()` function is the same type as the program's arguments: an array of strings `NULL`-terminated.
Following this steps, you can easily parse the program's arguments to fit in the `execvp()`:

1. Iterate through the program's arguments;
2. Find the position of the pipe symbol;
3. In that position, put `NULL` to signalize the end of the first command's arguments;
4. Save the address of the next position as the start of the second command's arguments.

After parsing the program's arguments, it is time to create a pipe and fork the process. In the child process, replace the `stdout` with the write-end of the pipe before executing the first command. In the parent process, replace the `stdin` with the read-end of the pipe before executing the second command.

Here is the entire code I wrote, ran and tested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define PIPE_SYMBOL ":"

int main ( int argc , char **argv ) {
    /* Validates the usage. At least is needed the program's name, two commands and the pipe symbol */
    if ( argc < 4 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: command-1 [args-1...] : command-2 [args-2...]\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* The start of the first comment is allways the start of the program arguments array */
    char **command1 = &argv[1];

    /* The start of the second command is undefined, once it depends where the pipe symbol is located */
    char **command2 = NULL;

    /* Finds the position of the pipe symbol */
    for ( int i = 0 ; argv[i] != NULL ; i++ ) {
        /* When found, ... */ 
        if ( strcmp(PIPE_SYMBOL, argv[i]) == 0 ) {
            /* ... replaces it for NULL, so the first command array is NULL terminated and... */
            argv[i] = NULL;
            /* ... the next position is the start of the second command */
            command2 = &argv[i+1];
            break;
        }
    }

    /* If the pipe symbol is missing or if there is no command after the pipe symbol, bad usage */
    if ( command2 == NULL || command2[0] == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: command-1 [args-1...] : command-2 [args-2...]\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pid_t pid;
    int pipefd[2];

    if ( pipe(pipefd) == -1 ) {
        perror("creating pipe");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ( (pid = fork()) == -1 ) {
        perror("creating child process");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    /* Child process executes the first command */
    if ( pid == 0 ) {
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup(pipefd[1]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execvp(command1[0], command1);
        perror("executing first command");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Parent process executes the second command */
    close(pipefd[1]);
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    dup(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[0]);
    execvp(command2[0], command2);
    perror("executing second command");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: Since `close(0)` frees the lowest-numbered unused int, `close(0); dup(rd)` will have the same effect as `dup2(rd, 0)`. Older Unix systems didn't even have `dup2` but only `dup` and were able to implement inter-process pipes just fine. Whatever the OP's problem is, it's not the use of `dup()`.

Comment: @user4815162342 you are totally right. I guess the problem is the parent process does not wait for the child process before `exit(0);` call.

Comment: okay so how can i force the exec to perform the action of executing ls | sort for example. how can I write that to the fd then have the exec command actually execute the command?

Comment: @itsMe read the "EDIT #2 (IMPLEMENTATION)" section of my main answer. If something is missing or if you don't understand what I wrote, call me again.

Comment: your contribution is eternally appreciated my fiend! your one post alone has taught me so much! a few different ways of looking at things as well as doing things, stuff i would have never even thought of or realized how to ever be able to do on my own.

Comment: absolutely stellar clean coding my friend i will be picking up much of the behaviors you have exhibited

Comment: @itsMe You're wellcome.

Answer (score 3):

You should always try to split the problem into smaller sub-problems that you can solve and verify first.

For example, consider if you had been provided the following **run.h**:

```c
#ifndef   RUN_H
#define   RUN_H
#include <sys/types.h>

/** Create a close-on-exec pipe with descriptors not standard streams
 *
 *  Both read and write end of the pipe will be close-on-exec,
 *  and neither of them will be 0 (stdin), 1 (stdout), or 2 (stderr).
 *
 * @fd      Read ([0]) and write ([1]) ends of the pipe
 * @return  0 if success, -1 with errno set if error
*/
int safe_pipe(int fd[2]);

/* pgid: */
enum {
    NEW_SESSION = -2,
    NO_CHANGE   = -1,
    NEW_PGROUP  = 0,
};

/* Descriptors: */
enum {
    DEV_NULL = -1,
    STANDARD_INPUT = 0,
    STANDARD_OUTPUT = 1,
    STANDARD_ERROR = 2,
};

/** Execute a binary in a child process
 *
 * This function uses a control pipe to check if the specified binary could be executed
 * (started; not completed!), and to provide the errno number if not.
 * It is careful to ensure even oddball descriptor configurations work.
 * It is up to the parent to close any pipe descriptors specified after the call.
 *
 * @pathname    Name or path to the binary to be executed.
 * @args        NULL-terminated array of command-line arguments.
 *              Note that args[0] is the command name itself.
 * @pgid        Process group to use: NEW_SESSION, NO_CHANGE, NEW_PGROUP,
 *              or a process group ID.  NO_CHANGE runs the child process
 *              in the same session and process group as the current process.
 * @infd        Standard input descriptor.  DEV_NULL, 0, or a pipe descriptor.
 * @outfd       Standard output descriptor. DEV_NULL, 1, or a pipe descriptor.
 * @errfd       Standard error descriptor.  DEV_NULL, 2, or a pipe descriptor.
 * @return      PID of the child process, or -1 with errno set if an error occurs.
*/
pid_t run(const char *pathname, const char *args[], pid_t pgid, int infd, int outfd, int errfd);

/** Wait for all child processes to finish, and reap them
 *
 * errno is always set when this function returns:
 *      ECHILD  if there are no more child processes
 *      EINTR   if wait was interrupted by signal delivery
 * or any other positive value returned by reaped().
 *
 * @reaped  NULL, or a function called for each reaped child process.
 *          First parameter is the PID of the child process that exited,
 *          the second parameter is the "packed" exit status code; see man 2 wait.
 *          If reaped() returns a negative value, wait_all_children() will
 *          immediately return with that value, keeping the same errno value.
 *          If reaped() returns a positive value, wait_all_children() will
 *          immediately return with the reaped process count, and that value in errno.
 * @return  Number of processes reaped, or negative if an error occurs.
*/
int wait_all_children(int (*reaped)(pid_t, int));

#endif /* RUN_H */
```

and its Creative Commons Zero -licensed (use as you wish!) implementation, **run.c**:

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "run.h"

/* Create a close-on-exec pipe whose read and write ends do not
 * overlap with standard descriptors (stdin, stdout, stderr).
 * Returns 0 if success, -1 with errno set if error.
*/
int  safe_pipe(int fd[2])
{
    unsigned int  close_mask = 0;
    int           err = 0;
    int           pfd[2];

    fd[0] = -1;
    fd[1] = -1;

    if (pipe2(pfd, O_CLOEXEC) == -1) {
        /* errno set by pipe2() */
        return -1;
    }

    do {
        /* Make sure read end does not shadow standard descriptors */
        while (pfd[0] >= 0 && pfd[0] <= 2) {
            close_mask |= 1 << pfd[0];
            pfd[0] = fcntl(pfd[0], F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC, 3);
            if (pfd[0] == -1) {
                err = errno;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (err)
            break;

        /* Make sure write end does not shadow standard descriptors */
        while (pfd[1] >= 0 && pfd[1] <= 2) {
            close_mask |= 1 << pfd[1];
            pfd[1] = fcntl(pfd[1], F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC, 3);
            if (pfd[1] == -1) {
                err = errno;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (err)
            break;

        /* Close any temporarily used descriptors. */
        if (close_mask & (1<<0))
            close(0);
        if (close_mask & (1<<1))
            close(1);
        if (close_mask & (1<<2))
            close(2);

        /* Success! */
        fd[0] = pfd[0];
        fd[1] = pfd[1];
        return 0;

    } while (0);

    /* Failed. Close all related descriptors. */
    if (pfd[0] != -1)
        close(pfd[0]);
    if (pfd[1] != -1)
        close(pfd[1]);
    if (close_mask & (1<<0))
        close(0);
    if (close_mask & (1<<1))
        close(1);
    if (close_mask & (1<<2))
        close(2);

    errno = err;
    return -1;
}


/* Open the null device to a specific descriptor.
*/
static int  dev_null(int to_descriptor)
{
    int  fd;

    if (to_descriptor == -1) {
        errno = EBADF;
        return -1;
    }

    close(to_descriptor);

    fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if (fd == -1)
        return -1; /* errno set by open() */
    if (fd == to_descriptor)
        return  0; /* We got lucky! */

    if (dup2(fd, to_descriptor) == -1) {
        const int  saved_errno = errno;
        close(fd);
        errno = saved_errno;
        return -1;
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}


/* Execute a binary with the specified command-line arguments
 * (args[] array terminated by a NULL pointer),
 * and redirecting standard input, output, and error to the specified descriptors
 * (which may, and should be, close-on-exec), or -1 to redirect to /dev/null.
 * pgid can be -2 for a new session, -1 for no change, 0 for new process group, or >0 for a specific process group.
 * Returns the PID of the new child process, or -1 with errno set if error.
*/
pid_t  run(const char *pathname, const char *args[], pid_t pgid, int infd, int outfd, int errfd)
{
    if (!pathname || !*pathname || !args || !args[0] || !args[0][0]) {
        /* NULL or empty pathname (path or name) to the executable. */
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    /* Create the control pipe we use between parent and child to monitor exec() success/failure. */
    int  ctrlfd[2];
    if (safe_pipe(ctrlfd) == -1) {
        /* errno set by safe_pipe(). */
        return -1;
    }

    pid_t  child = fork();
    if (child == -1) {
        /* Cannot fork a child process. */
        const int  saved_errno = errno;
        close(ctrlfd[0]);
        close(ctrlfd[1]);
        errno = saved_errno;
        return -1;

    } else
    if (!child) {
        /* Child process. */

        unsigned int  close_mask = 0;
        int           err = 0;
        do {

            /* Close parent (read) end of the control pipe. */
            close(ctrlfd[0]);

            /* Adjust process group. */
            if (pgid == NEW_SESSION) {
                if (setsid() == -1) {
                    err = errno;
                    break;
                }
            } else
            if (pgid == NEW_PGROUP) {
                if (setpgid(0, 0) == -1) {
                    err = errno;
                    break;
                }
            } else
            if (pgid > 0) {
                if (setpgid(0, pgid) == -1) {
                    err = errno;
                    break;
                }
            } else
            if (pgid != NO_CHANGE) {
                err = EINVAL;
                break;
            }

            /* Make sure infd does not shadow standard output or standard error. */
            while (infd == 1 || infd == 2) {
                close_mask |= 1 << infd;
                infd = fcntl(infd, F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC, 3);
                if (infd == -1) {
                    err = errno;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (err)
                break;

            /* Make sure outfd does not shadow standard input or standard error. */
            while (outfd == 0 || outfd == 2) {
                close_mask |= 1 << outfd;
                outfd = fcntl(outfd, F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC, 3);
                if (outfd == -1) {
                    err = errno;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (err)
                break;

            /* Make sure errfd does not shadow standard input or standard output. */
            while (errfd == 0 || errfd == 1) {
                close_mask |= 1 << errfd;
                errfd = fcntl(errfd, F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC, 3);
                if (errfd == -1) {
                    err = errno;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (err)
                break;

            /* Close unneeded descriptors. */
            if ((close_mask & (1<<0)) || infd == -1)
                close(0);
            if ((close_mask & (1<<1)) || outfd == -1)
                close(1);
            if ((close_mask & (1<<2)) || errfd == -1)
                close(2);

            /* Redirect standard input. */
            if (infd == DEV_NULL) {
                if (dev_null(0) == -1) {
                    err = errno;
                    break;
                }
                infd = 0;
            } else
            if (infd != 0) {
                if (dup2(infd, 0) == -1) {
                    err = errno;
                    break;
                }
                close(infd);
                infd = 0;
            }

            /* Redirect standard output. */
            if (outfd == DEV_NULL) {
                if (dev_null(1) == -1) {
                    err = errno;
                    break;
                }
                outfd = 1;
            } else
            if (outfd != 1) {
                if (dup2(outfd, 1) == -1) {
                    err = errno;
                    break;
                }
                close(outfd);
                outfd = 1;
            }

            /* Redirect standard error. */
            if (errfd == DEV_NULL) {
                if (dev_null(2) == -1) {
                    err = errno;
                    break;
                }
                errfd = 2;
            } else
            if (errfd != 2) {
                if (dup2(errfd, 2) == -1) {
                    err = errno;
                    break;
                }
                close(errfd);
                errfd = 2;
            }

            /* Make sure the standard descriptors are not close-on-exec. */
            if (fcntl(0, F_SETFD, 0) == -1 ||
                fcntl(1, F_SETFD, 0) == -1 ||
                fcntl(2, F_SETFD, 0) == -1) {
                err = errno;
                break;
            }

            /* Close the unneeded temporary descriptors. */
            if (close_mask & (1<<0))
                close(0);
            if (close_mask & (1<<1))
                close(1);
            if (close_mask & (1<<2))
                close(2);
            close_mask = 0;

            /* Execute. */
            if (strchr(pathname, '/'))
                execv(pathname, (char *const *)args);   /* pathname has a slash, so it is a path to a binary */
            else
                execvp(pathname, (char *const *)args);  /* pathname has no slash, so it specifies the binary name only */

            /* Failed. */
            err = errno;
        } while (0);

        /* Send err to parent via the control pipe. */
        {
            const char        *ptr = (const char *)(&err);
            const char *const  end = (const char *)(&err) + sizeof err;
            while (ptr < end) {
                ssize_t  n = write(ctrlfd[1], ptr, (size_t)(end - ptr));
                if (n > 0) {
                    ptr += n;
                } else
                if (n != -1) {
                    /* Should never occur */
                    break;
                } else
                if (errno != EINTR) {
                    /* I/O error writing to the pipe too! */
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* The kernel will close all open descriptors in the process. */
        exit(127);
    }

    /* Parent process. */

    /* Close read end of control pipe, so we detect if the child process exec() succeeded. */
    close(ctrlfd[1]);

    /* Read from the control pipe, to determine if child process exec succeeds or not. */
    {
        int          err = 0;
        char        *ptr = (char *)(&err);
        char *const  end = (char *)(&err) + sizeof err;

        while (ptr < end) {
            ssize_t  n = read(ctrlfd[0], ptr, (size_t)(end - ptr));
            if (n > 0) {
                ptr += n;
            } else
            if (n == 0) {
                break;
            } else
            if (n != -1) {
                err = EIO;
                ptr = end;
                break;
            } else
            if (errno != EINTR) {
                err = errno;
                ptr = end;
                break;
            }
        }

        close(ctrlfd[0]);

        /* Treat partially received errors and received zero as EIO. */
        if (ptr > (char *)(&err)) {
            if (ptr != end || !err)
                err = EIO;
        }

        if (err) {
            /* Child failed to exec; reap it. */

            /* Reap child process. Ignore errors, and retry if interrupted. */
            pid_t  p;
            do {
                p = waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
            } while (p == -1 && errno == EINTR);

            errno = err;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /* Success. */
    errno = 0;
    return child;
}


int wait_all_children(int (*reaped)(pid_t, int))
{
    int  count = 0;

    while (1) {
        int    status = 0;
        pid_t  pid;

        pid = wait(&status);
        if (pid == -1) {
            /* errno set by wait() */
            return count;
        } else
        if (pid < 1) {
            /* C library or Linux kernel bug! */
            errno = EIO;
            return count;
        }

        count++;

        if (reaped) {
            int  retval = reaped(pid, status);
            if (retval < 0) {
                /* errno set by reaped() */
                return retval;
            } else
            if (retval > 0) {
                errno = retval;
                return count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and a **Makefile** to build an example program from example.c:

```makefile
CC      := gcc
CFLAGS  := -Wall -Wextra -O2
LDFLAGS :=
TARGETS := example

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGETS)

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGETS) *.o

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^

example: example.o run.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

Note that this forum converts <kbd>Tab</kbd>s to spaces, and Makefile indentation must use <kbd>Tabs</kbd> and not spaces.  Fortunately, running `sed -e 's|^  *|\t|' -i Makefile` fixes the above – and most other Makefiles – by converting initial spaces to a tab.

The idea with the above is to help you get started on the correct path:

- `safe_pipe()` creates a pipe where both ends are closed automatically when you do any exec() call.  Even if you have closed some of the standard descriptors (standard input, output, or error), it makes sure the pipe ends do not interfere with the standard descriptors.
- `wait_all_children()` waits for all immediate children of the current process (i.e. those that this process has forked), until there are no more children, waiting is interrupted by a signal delivery, or the optional reporting function (which it takes as a parameter) returns nonzero.
- `run()` forks a child process, redirecting the standard descriptors as necessary, and even taking care of process groups.  It uses a control pipe to detect exec() errors, and does not wait for the child process to exit, only for the child process to start.

  Process groups are useful, because if each logical task is in their own process group, you can send a signal (like KILL or TERM) to each process in a specific group, by using the negated process group ID.  This ensures that for complex tasks, when the entire task needs to be killed, no matter how many processes it has already forked, you can clean it all up nicely.  For simple commands, we don't worry about process groups, though.

Examining the above is better done after we do a simple example program, say one that runs `ls -laF | tr a-z A-Z | cat`, which lists all files in the current directory, but converts lower case a to z to upper case, using three child processes:

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "run.h"

int report(pid_t pid, int code)
{
    if (WIFEXITED(code)) {
        if (WEXITSTATUS(code))
            printf("Process %d exited with status %d.\n", (int)pid, WEXITSTATUS(code));
        else
            printf("Process %d exited with success (status 0).\n", (int)pid);
    } else
    if (WIFSIGNALED(code)) {
        printf("Process %d died from signal %d.\n", (int)pid, WTERMSIG(code));
    } else {
        printf("Process %d died from unknown causes.\n", (int)pid);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *cmd_a[] = { "ls", "-laF", NULL };
    const char *cmd_b[] = { "tr", "a-z", "A-Z", NULL };
    const char *cmd_c[] = { "cat", NULL };
    int    a_to_b[2], b_to_c[2];
    pid_t  a, b, c;

    if (safe_pipe(a_to_b) == -1 || safe_pipe(b_to_c) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create pipes: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    c = run(cmd_c[0], cmd_c, NO_CHANGE, b_to_c[0], STANDARD_OUTPUT, STANDARD_ERROR);
    if (c == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", cmd_c[0], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    b = run(cmd_b[0], cmd_b, NO_CHANGE, a_to_b[0], b_to_c[1], STANDARD_ERROR);
    if (b == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", cmd_b[0], strerror(errno));
        kill(c, SIGKILL);
        wait_all_children(NULL);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    a = run(cmd_a[0], cmd_a, NO_CHANGE, DEV_NULL, a_to_b[1], STANDARD_ERROR);
    if (a == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", cmd_a[0], strerror(errno));
        kill(b, SIGKILL);
        kill(c, SIGKILL);
        wait_all_children(NULL);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    close(a_to_b[0]);
    close(a_to_b[1]);
    close(b_to_c[0]);
    close(b_to_c[1]);

    wait_all_children(report);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `report()` function just reports which child process has exited and how.  You can omit it, using `wait_all_children(NULL);` instead of `wait_all_children(report);`, but the report function is useful for debugging and examining what kind of exit statuses you can observe in different situations.

We have to pipes: `a_to_b`, and `b_to_c`.  The first descriptor of the pair (`a_to_b[0]` and `b_to_c[0]`) is always the read end, and the second (`a_to_b[1]` and `b_to_c[1]`) the write end.  Our three child processes are `a`, `b`, and `c`, so we want `a`'s standard output to be `a_to_b[1]`, `b`'s standard input to be `a_to_b[0]`, `b`'s standard output to be `b_to_c[1]`, and `c`'s standard input to be `b_to_c[1]`.

We need to create the pipes first.

Then, we need to run (fork and exec) the child processes.  Because the children will block until they get input (or they see an end of input), we create the child processes in the pipe from last to first: first the "consumers", and then the "producers".  This way, if we fail until the entire chain is okay, the producers should still be waiting for input.

If we fail to create some of the child processes, we do need to kill the already started processes, and preferably wait for them to exit (usually called, *reap them*).

When the child processes have been started, the parent process needs to close its copies of the pipe descriptors, so that when the "producers" (first processes in the pipe list) exit and close the write ends of the pipes, the read end reports end of input.

If the parent process does not close its copies of the pipe (write end) descriptors, the "consumers" (the child processes that read from the pipes) will never detect the end-of-input – because theoretically, the *parent* process could still write to the pipe! – and everything will seem like it "hangs".

At this point, the processes in the pipe do their work.  The parent process could do other stuff at this point.  (One interesting scenario is when one wishes to use *filters*: a chain of processes, usually a script, that converts data from one format to another.  It is quite possible for the read end of the filter output pipe (or pipe chain) and the write end of the input pipe to be accessible to the parent, so that the parent writes the data to be transformed at the write end, and reads the transformed data from the read end.  It is a bit tricky, because we cannot assume we can write everything before we read anything, so usually *nonblocking* I/O with `select()` or `poll()` is used.  Nothing *hard* per se, just needs to be done correctly.)

Since there is nothing for the parent process to do but wait for the pipe processes to do their work, the parent just waits for them to exit.

Because of the Makefile, you only need to run `make all && ./example` to compile and run the example program.

Because the overall problem is split into sub-problems (creating the pipes in a manner that causes least issues with standard streams, and that do not accidentally leak to the wrong child processes; and forking and starting a child process redirecting its standard streams, in a robust and reliable manner), the example program is short and easy to understand at the conceptual level.

After playing with that example, it would be time to explore and explain how **run.c** implements the functions, and why the choices it makes were made, but I'm already going to get downvoted to negative scores for not answering the stated question, so I shall stop here.  Nevertheless, I still believe that approaching the problem this way, step by step, building the solution on top of tested and understood parts, instead of trying to "fix" OP's current code, is the correct "answer" here.  (Then again, this is exactly why I post only as a guest, never registering.)