# Some pipe file descriptor stays open even though i close everything

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

```
static int pipefd[2];
static pid_t cpid = 0;

void sigtimeout(int num) {
    kill(cpid, 9);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    close(pipefd[0]);
    pipe(pipefd);
    write(pipefd[1], "T/O\n", 5);
}

void settimer(float time) {
    struct itimerval timer;
    timer.it_value.tv_sec = (int)time;
    timer.it_value.tv_usec = (timeout - (int)time) * 1000000;
    timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);
}

pid_t popen2(char *cmd) {
    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1)
        return -1;
    int pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        return -1;
    if (pid == 0) {
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        close(STDERR_FILENO);
        dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", cmd, NULL);
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else
        settimer(timeout);
    return pid;
}

void getcmd(const Block *block, char *output)
{
    if (block->signal)
    {
        output[0] = block->signal;
        output++;
    }
    strcpy(output, block->icon);
    char *cmd;

    if (button)
    {
        cmd = strcat(exportstring, block->command);
        cmd[14] = '0' + button;
        cpid = popen2(cmd);
        if (cpid == -1) {
            close(pipefd[0]);
            close(pipefd[1]);
            return;
        }
        cmd[16] = '\0';

    }
    else
    {
        cmd = block->command;
        cpid = popen2(cmd);
        if (cpid == -1) {
            close(pipefd[0]);
            close(pipefd[1]);
            return;
        }
    }
    button = 0;

    waitpid(cpid, 0, 0);
    settimer(0);
    kill(cpid, 9);
    close(pipefd[1]);

    int i = strlen(block->icon);
    read(pipefd[0], output+i, CMDLENGTH-i-delimLen);
    close(pipefd[0]);
    for (char *c = output; *c; c++)
        if (*c == '\n') {
            c[1] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    i = strlen(output);
    if (delim[0] != '\0') {
        //only chop off newline if one is present at the end
        i = output[i-1] == '\n' ? i-1 : i;
        strncpy(output+i, delim, delimLen); 
    }
    else
        output[i++] = '\0';
}
```

So I'm trying to modify dwmblocks to add a timeout functionality. That way, if a command hangs, the whole status bar doesn't freeze.

Everything seems to work fine, but there is one little catch.

My code makes my whole linux system crash, cause it leaves some file descriptor open every time it runs a command. As you probably know, linux has protections against that, so every other application on my system that tries to open a file descriptor crashes too.

Thing is, I'm literally closing every pipe I open in my code, even the ones that open automatically when you fork. I just can't figure out what the problem is.

I'd really appreciate any help.

BTW: I'm only putting the relevant code here, because the problem is with the file descriptors. This is the only place where I work with file descriptors in my code.

Feel free to ask for more parts of the code if you feel it's relevant in some way :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `popen2()` function leaves both pipe ends in the parent process open.  Parent should always close the write end (that the child process writes to).  Perhaps that is the one that leaks.

If you were to print `(int)getpid()` to show the process ID, you could list the pseudofiles in `/proc/PID/fd/` as those describe the file descriptor that process has currently open.  (If you use `ls -laF /proc/PID/fd/` with the process ID number instead of `PID`, you can even see what/where the descriptors are open.)

In [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66415261/15296379), I recently showed how one can implement a `safe_pipe()`, `run()`, and `wait_all_children()` functions for exploring complicated piping schemes between child processes.  `safe_pipe()` sets the close-on-exec flag for each pipe descriptor by default, and `run()` clears that flag only in the child process if it uses such a descriptor, so the forked child processes do not have the other pipes' descriptors open at all.  The included example.c also shows how the parent process must close all pipe ends used by the child processes when the child processes have been started, so that the child processes correctly detect end of inputs.  (If the parent process has write ends open, then it *could* write to the pipe, so any child reading from the read end of that pipe will never see end-of-input.)

If necessary or helpful, I'm willing to explain how `safe_pipe()` and `run()` and `wait_all_children()` do what they do, and also why.  In particular, `run()` uses an extra pipe between the child process prior to exec, and the parent process, to detect problems exec'ing the specified binary (and other errors).  While there may be typos in there, the two are very robust implementations, not leaking resources etc.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: It might be a race condition due to an undefined interaction between settimer and sleep. What a headache...

Answer (score 0):

Well this is embarassing hahaha

I had a typo in my settimer function : timeout was supposed to be time.

So the real problem was due to a racing condition, even though my piping system is far from perfect.

That goes to show how hard bugs can be to debug sometimes.