# posix_spawn pipe dmesg to python script

Tags: c, linux, posix, embedded-linux

I've got several USB to 422 adapters in my test system. I've used FTProg to give each adapter a specific name: Sensor1, Sensor2, etc. They will all be plugged in at power on. I don't want to hard code each adapter to a specific ttyUSBx. I want the drivers to figure out which tty it needs to use. I'm developing in C for a linux system. My first thought was to something like this in my startup code.

```
system("dmesg | find_usb.py");
```

The python script would find the devices since each one has a unique Product Description. Then using the usb tree to associate each device with its ttyUSBx. The script would then create /tmp/USBDevs which would just be a simple device:tty pairing that would be easy for the C code to search.

I've been told...DoN't UsE sYsTeM...use posix_spawn(). But I'm having problems getting the output of dmesg piped to my python script. This isn't working

```
char *my_args[] = {"dmesg", "|", "find_usb.py", NULL};
pid_t pid;
int status;

status = posix_spawn(&pid, "/bin/dmesg", NULL, NULL, my_args, NULL);
if(status == 0){
   if(waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != -1);{
printf("posix_spawn exited: %i", status);
}
```

I've been trying to figure out how to do this with posix_spawn_file_actions(), but I'm not allowed to hit the peak of the 'Ballmer Curve' at work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `/dev/ttyUSB*` devices, write udev rules to generate named symlinks to the devices.  For a brief how-to, see [here](https://dev.to/enbis/how-udev-rules-can-help-us-to-recognize-a-usb-to-serial-device-over-dev-tty-interface-pbk).  Basically, you'll have an udev rule for each device, ending with say `SYMLINK+=Sensor-name`, and in your program, use `/dev/Sensor-name` for each sensor.  (I do recommend using `Sensor-` prefix, noting the initial Capital letter, as all device names are currently lowercase.  This avoids any clashes with existing devices.)

These symlinks will then only exist when the matching device is plugged in, and will point to the correct device (/dev/ttyUSB* in this case).  When the device is removed, udev automagically deletes the symlink also.  Just make sure your udev rule identifies the device precisely (not just vendor:device, but serial number also).  I'd expect the rule to look something like

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="VVVV", ATTRS{idProduct}=="PPPP", ATTRS{serial}=="SSSSSSSS", SYMLINK+="Sensor-name"
```

where `VVVV` is the USB Vendor ID (four hexadecimal digits), `PPPP` is the USB Product ID (four hexadecimal digits), and `SSSSSSSS` is the serial number string.  You can see these values using e.g. `udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB*` when the device is plugged in.

If you still insist on parsing dmesg output, using your own script is a good idea.

You could use `FILE *handle = popen("dmesg | find_usb.py", "r");` and read from `handle` like it was a file.  When complete, close the handle using `int exitstatus = pclose(handle);`.  See [man popen](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) and [man pclose](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pclose.3.html) for the details, and [man 2 wait](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) for the `WIFEXITED()`, `WEXITSTATUS()`, `WIFSIGNALED()`, `WTERMSIG()` macros you'll need to use to examine `exitstatus` (although in your case, I suppose you can just ignore any errors).

If you do want to use [posix_spawn()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_spawn.3.html) (or roughly equivalently, [fork()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [execvp()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html)), you'd need to set up at least one pipe (to read the output of the spawned command) – two if you spawn/fork+exec both `dmesg` and your Python script –, and that gets a bit more complicated.  See [man pipe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) for details on that.  Personally, I would rewrite the Python script so that it executes `dmesg` itself internally, and only outputs the device name(s). With `posix_spawn()`, you'd init a `posix_file_actions_t`, with three actions: _adddup2() to duplicate the write end of the pipe to STDOUT_FILENO, and two _addclose()s to close both ends of the pipe.  However, I myself prefer to use `fork()` and `exec()` instead, somewhat similar to the example [by Glärbo in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66415261/16311026).

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I'm not married to using posix_spawn. I'm new to the group, and most of my career I've been writing bare metal C for small embedded sensors. I tried using 'system' in another section of code. My merge request was promptly denied and I was told to use posix_spawn so I was just trying to avoid that fate again.

Creating a udev rule looks like a really clean way to solve this problem, guess I'll be digging into the install script Monday and removing comments in my code that look something like this.

// DoN't UsE sYsTeM
// ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
system("dmesg | find_usb.py);